# php mail localhost

Tags: php

I keep getting this error:

```
 Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set
```

I'm using a windows machine and php mail settings are:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

;For Win32 only.
 ;http://php.net/sendmail-from

sendmail_from = sales@megadirectory.co.uk
```

Could someone tell me what settings to put in my php.ini file or give me some ini_set settings

Thanks 
Sam

Comment: you can use SMTP class rather than change setting in php.ini go to PHPclasses.org and download suitable class

Answer (score 2):

You should have working SMTP server and set it address and port into php.ini.